# getting rid of Joomla warning errors in IE browser caused by mootools and jquery conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, mootools

I am getting website developed here: http://extremeprodigy.com/projects/leelam36/

It shows an error in IE browser only in the status bar saying 'Done but with errors'. website is built with Joomla and mootools and jquery is being used. There seems to be a conflict but we are unable to resolve.

The current developer is having problem with mootools-compressed.js file and the erros description is as below:

```
TypeError:$(filter) || document).getElementsBySelector is not a function
```

Is there any way we can suppress or disable these warnings through code from showing in IE status bar?

Any help is much appreciated.

Saeed

Answer (score 0):

There is two solutions:

- You find the conflict and resolve it.
- You rely only on jQuery OR Mootools, not both.

Even if the less libraries you load the best it is, you probably can resolve your conflict by using `jQuery()` selector instead of `$()` everywhere you use jQuery. This should work. If you use jQuery plugins, make sure you replace the selector to  `jQuery()` there too.

Hope it helps...

Answer (score -1):

Use a `try {} catch () {}` statement.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch

Comment: I don't know why my answer was down voted.  Using a try...catch statement will indeed suppress the errors.  It won't solve the errors, but that wasn't the question.